# Realtek Ethernet not working after kernel update

Tags: networking, centos, ethernet, kernel, centos-7

After updating the CentOS 7.7 kernel from 3.10.0-957.27.2 to 3.10.0-1062.9.1, the Ethernet stopped working. The LEDs on the Ethernet port wouldn't light up and any attempt to ping anything resulted in a "host not reachable".

Everything looked ok with the files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, and the output in `/var/log/messages` seemed to indicate that the interface was coming up correctly. Finally I booted the older 3.10.0-957.27.2 kernel and the Ethernet port immediately began working again.

When I run `lspci -nnk` it lists the Ethernet controller as:

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

The output from `lspci` is identical under both kernels, including the "r8169" driver in use.

It looks like the Realtek drivers are included with the kernel because I see a lot of Realtek files under directories like:

`/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek`

But I see that although the Realtek driver filenames are the same, the sizes and dates have been updated for the newer kernel.

What's the best way to get the Ethernet controller working with the latest kernel?

Comment: What does `ip link show` outputs on the new kernel?

Comment: Possible regression. https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=16413

Comment: This also happens with the 5.6 mainline branch as well. I can confirm the 4.4 long term branch is unaffected as of `kernel-lt-4.4.224-1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the OP and I found an easy solution thanks to Kate who commented above with a link to a CentOS bug report. Apparently, this is a known issue in the 1062 kernel and the driver is somehow not being loaded in the right order.

A quick fix to immediately activate the Ethernet port is to unload the r8169 driver and then reload it, but this doesn't survive a reboot:

```
# rmmod r8169
# modprobe r8169
```

You can skip that entirely though and fix the whole problem with one line that loads the Realtek module at the correct time using a config file. I can confirm that this does survive multiple reboots:

```
# echo realtek > /etc/modules-load.d/realtek.conf
(then reboot)
```

One thing that's curious is that when I booted from the old 957 kernel and did an `lsmod` I found that the realtek module wasn't being loaded then either, even though the Ethernet port worked fine. And the r8169 module was being loaded by both the old 957 kernel and the new 1062 kernel. But anyway, something's not being loaded in the right order by the 1062 kernel and this fixes it, so I'm all good now. Thanks again to Kate!

Comment: I was looking for a solution since hours. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: On CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) using kernel-ml-5.11.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 your rmmod, modprobe commands worked, but the realtek.conf file didn't.  To survive reboots I had to use the load-realtek-driver.service solution.

Answer (score 3):

The only solution that I came across is this:

```
cat <<EOF| sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/load-realtek-driver.service
[Unit]
Description=Load Realtek drivers.
Before=network-online.target
    
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/rmmod r8169
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/modprobe r8169
  
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
    
sudo systemctl enable load-realtek-driver.service
```

Or your an also just open up the service file like this using Nano or any other text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/load-realtek-driver.service
```

And then adding this to that file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Load Realtek drivers.
Before=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/rmmod r8169
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/modprobe r8169

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then start the service like this:

```
sudo systemctl start load-realtek-driver.service
```

And enable it so it can start on reboot like this:

```
sudo systemctl enable load-realtek-driver.service
```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: That `cat <<EOF| sudo tee` is kinda crazy. Just open up `/etc/systemd/system/load-realtek-driver.service` with a text editor and then add that text afterwards and up to `EOF` to it.

Comment: It does the job at once, instead of step by step!

Comment: Many systems don’t have `tee` installed. Opening up an editor and adding text and then saving it is not hard. Better clearly state what is being done instead of making it just one complex command.

Comment: Yeah great explaintation, many systems don't have nano, wget etc aswell which we install them, however, newer versions of linux they do have tee installed by default. At least in centos 7/8 which i am using.

Comment: Just so you know, I think this is a good answer. But I believe if the basic concept is conveyed, the shortcut can exist as well. Not having some tools installed by default is fine; the basic concept is just this is a text config, this is where it goes and this is how you get the software to load it.

Comment: Actually the one here won't work which i tried them: # echo realtek > /etc/modules-load.d/realtek.conf
(then reboot) actually it worked in kernel-ml 5.8 but not in higher versions of kernel-ml.

Comment: Is tee used just so you can sudo it?  I.e. I assume running this as root is just as good:
cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/load-realtek-driver.service

Answer (score 0):

also use  crontab -e  add this command

```
@reboot sleep 20  && /usr/sbin/rmmod  r8169 && /usr/sbin/modprobe r8169
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please expand upon your answer to make it clearer what you think that the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

A rather old thread but still current issue I have addressed in 2023, caused by the **Secure Boot** option in BIOS/EFI.

I wonder how many people has been trying booting to older kernels or trying to gather module/driver information and injecting updated modules to no avail.

Just *disabling the Secure Boot option* was the (only) solution in my case. Linux kernel modules/drivers are just not always signed and most certainly *will* cause conflict with (and be disabled by) the secured machine BIOS.

Imho Secure Boot just causes more problems than it prevents or solves.

Hope this helps.